# Send message via TCP in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have been trying to send message on tcp, but these code seems to give strange error on  Delphi 7, thou I tried similar code on Delphi XE and it works fine. Im using Indy 10 on both XE and Delphi 7.

```
type
  TClient   = class(TIdContext) 
    PeerIP      : String;          
    RcvdMsg     : String;

    procedure SendResponse(const AResponse: String);
  end;
```

**...**

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  NewClient:   TClient;
begin
  with TClient(AContext) do
  begin
    NewClient.PeerIP      := Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
    NewClient.RcvdMsg     := Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
  end;
end;
```

**...**

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Context: TClient;
  List: TList;
  I: Integer;
begin

  List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
    begin
      Context := TClient(List[I]);
      MessageBox(0,pChar(Context.PeerIP),0,0); // shows wierd string
 (*     if (Context.PeerIP = IP) then
      begin 
        //didn't get to here
        Context.SendResponse('msg');
        Break;
      end              *)

    end;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Any way to solve it ?

**EDIT:**

```
type
      TClient   = class(TIdServerContext) 
        PeerIP      : String;          
        RcvdMsg     : String;

        procedure SendResponse(const AResponse: String);
      end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 1234;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := not IdTCPServer1.Active;
  IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TClient;
end;
```

I still can't send message.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Context: TClient;
      List: TList;
      I: Integer;
    begin

      List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
      try
        for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
        begin
          Context := TClient(List[I]);
          MessageBox(0,pChar(Context.PeerIP),0,0); // blank
     (*     if (Context.PeerIP = IP) then
          begin 
            //didn't get to here
            Context.SendResponse('msg');
            Break;
          end              *)

        end;
      finally
        IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Is the output really "weird string"?

Comment: what i meant is weird ascii characters, or i don't know what you guys call it

Answer (score 2):

`TClient` needs to derive from `TIdServerContext`, not `TIdContext`.  And make sure you are assigning the `TIdTCPServer.ContextClass` property before activating the server if you are not already doing so, or else your typecasts will be invalid:

```
type
  TClient = class(TIdServerContext)
    ...
  end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TClient;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: thank you for the help, I actually tried `TIdServerContext`, but the result is the same, doesn't work also if added  `IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TClient;`...I edited my post

Comment: You must set the `ContextClass` **before** activating the server, otherwise you risk having clients connect to the server and end up using the default `TIdServerContext` class before you have updated the `ContextClass` to use your custom class.